# How do I prevent deletion of parent if it has child records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have looked through the Ruby on Rails guides and I can't seem to figure out how to prevent someone from deleting a Parent record if it has Children.  For example.  If my database has **CUSTOMERS** and each customer can have multiple **ORDERS**, I want to prevent someone from deleting a customer if it has any orders in the database.  They should only be able to delete a customer if it has no orders.

Is there a way when defining the association between models to enforce this behavior?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could do this in a callback:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  before_destroy :check_for_orders

  private

  def check_for_orders
    if orders.count > 0
      errors.add_to_base("cannot delete customer while orders exist")
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10257516/17410) for a better way to do this.

Comment: This is the best way.  It's the cleanest, and it's exactly where I would look for such a filter if I was working on your code.  Returning "false" in the callback is what tells rails not to proceed with the action.

Comment: You may want to consider using Errors#add(:base, msg) instead.

Comment: I've created a small ActiveRecord plugin for applications that need this functionality in various models: https://github.com/Florent2/prevent_destroy_if_any

Comment: This is NOT the best way. A simple `dependent: :restrict` is, as per @Mauro's answer. Though I suspect this answer was accepted before the introduction of dependent restrict.

Comment: @Zenph Yup, :dependent => :restrict was added later, and is the better solution.

Comment: @zetetic I think it would be beneficial for others if you updated your answer. Some visitors might just take the first snippet they find (which happens to be outdated and overcomplicated). I came here from Google myself.

Comment: @zetetic on an unrelated note, I love the fact you're a long-term Railist :) Bring on Rails 4!

Comment: @Zenph @zetetic `dependent: :restrict` will cause unhandled exception in default scaffold. This answer is currently more complete. The "better" answer needs to be augmented with a way of handling the exception at base controller level. Even then, the situation is not "exceptional".

Comment: @nurettin now there is the dependent: :restrict_with_error option to handle the case you talked about 5 years ago. The accepted answer should be changed or updated.

Answer (score 117):

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :dependent => :restrict # raises ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError
```

Edit: as of Rails 4.1, `:restrict` is not a valid option, and instead you should use either `:restrict_with_error` or `:restrict_with_exception`

Eg.:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :dependent => :restrict_with_error
```

Comment: Can the restriction message be customised?

Comment: Can this answer please be updated to reflect changes in Rails 4.1 and above? "Removed support for deprecated option :restrict for :dependent in associations." http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html. The :dependent option must be one of [:destroy, :delete_all, :nullify, :restrict_with_error, :restrict_with_exception]

Comment: hi thank you - what is the difference between restricting with errors vs exceptions?

Comment: `restrict_with_error` adds a Rails error to the respective attribute, while `restrict_with_exception` raises the mentioned exception. See https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-one-dependent

Answer (score 0):

Try using [filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) to hook in custom code during request processing.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to avoid providing your users a link to deletion in this scenario.

```
link_to_unless !@customer.orders.empty?
```

Another way would be to handle this in your controller:

```
if !@customer.orders.empty?
  flash[:notice] = "Cannot delete a customer with orders"
  render :action => :some_action
end
```

Or, as Joe suggests, before_filters could work well here and would probably be a much more DRY way of doing this, especially if you want this type of behavior for more models than just Customer.