# Rails 3. before_destroy validation to prevent deleting parent records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have shipments and invoices.

invoice belongs to shipment
shipment has one invoice

If the shipment does have an invoice, then the shipment shouldn't be able to be deleted. I need to set this up in the models because I'm using ActiveAdmin.

So I did this in shipment.rb

```
has_one :invoice
before_destroy :check_for_invoice

private

def check_for_invoice
  unless invoice.nil?
    self.errors[:base] << "Cannot delete shipment while its invoice exists."
  end
end
```

But I just get a yellow message saying "Shipment cannot be deleted" but it was in fact deleted.

How can I prevent the shipment from being deleted?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `before_destroy` callback needs a true/false value to determine whether or not to proceeed.

Add a `return false` to your `check_for_invoice` like so:

```
has_one :invoice
before_destroy :check_for_invoice

private

def check_for_invoice   
  unless invoice.nil?     
    self.errors[:base] << "Cannot delete shipment while its invoice exists."
    return false   
  end 
end
```

Comment: Ah that's right! I forgot to return false. I also posted this part of the code wrong `if invoice.nil?`, it's supposed to be `unless invoice.nil?` instead.

Comment: I was curious about the logic - but thought it might just be something weird you were doing. I'll update my answer to make it match for posterity's sake.

Comment: Check [this answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10257516/703233) for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

My 2 cents in shipment.rb

```
has_one :invoice, dependent: :restrict
```

I think that it'll work, I saw this solution in another thread. I'm tryng right now in my models.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html):

> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the associated action are cancelled.

So try this:

```
self.errors[:base] << "Cannot delete shipment while its invoice exists." and return false
```

Comment: @Jordan you're right that `return` is mostly not idiomatic in Ruby, but what if the line is not the last one in the method (plus consider refactoring)? Or what if you later add other statements in the method and forget to add the return? I think these are the reasons why you do see `and return false` used in rails projects...

Comment: Alright, that's a compelling enough argument. I've rolled back my revision.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4:

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :invoice, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

will do the trick. If you want an exception instead of an error use `:restrict_with_exception`. See more at [the relevant api docs page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options).

For Rails 3 (maybe earlier too) try:

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :invoice, dependent: :restrict
```